# How to run latest version of awesome?

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

### Question

What can I do to get to awesome >= 4.3?

### About my problem

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and running awesome 4.2 (installed with `apt`). But now I want to use some widgets that uses `awful.popup` and that was introduced in awesome 4.3. o I thought I could get that working by compiling my own new version.

So following the [build instructions](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome) i did:

```
git clone https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome
cd awesome
make
```

Then everything seems to be working until it finally fails as:

```
...
[ 87%] Generating API documentation
Error: no suitable Lua interpreter found
Error: supported versions are: 5.2 5.1
CMakeFiles/ldoc.dir/build.make:289: recipe for target 'doc/index.html' failed
make[3]: *** [doc/index.html] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:211: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ldoc.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ldoc.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:151: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'cmake-build' failed
make: *** [cmake-build] Error 2
```

So as far as far as I understand it I'm on Lua5.3 and `awesomeConfig.cmake` tells me 5.3 should be valid:

```
# 5.1 <= LUA_VERSION < 5.4
```

Current running awesome version is:

```
$ awesome --version
awesome v4.2 (Human after all)
 • Compiled against Lua 5.3.3 (running with Lua 5.3)
 • D-Bus support: ✔
 • execinfo support: ✔
 • xcb-randr version: 1.5
 • LGI version: 0.9.2
```

Comment: It's crashing while creating the manual `ldoc`.  If you're alright with reading the manual online, try `make GENERATE_DOC=OFF GENERATE_MANPAGES=OFF`  https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/master/awesomeConfig.cmake

Comment: I copied your command without success. I also tried some variants but I get the same exact output regardless what I try.

Comment: I thought that's how you passed `make` args, but it's been a while.  Maybe they need to be prepended with double dashes, and/or set to False `--GENERATE_DOC=False` instead.  I don't think you have to go so far as set them as environment variables.  Really thought that's how you do it.  Well, if you can't find a solution in https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues?q=is%3Aissue+ldoc then just edit that `awesomeConfig.cmake` so it no longer includes the generate_doc portions, then it should hopefully compile.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Ubuntu, it is useful to first run `apt build-dep awesome -y`. It  will install everything needed for `make` to work. Note that if you have some weirdly configured Lua, the error may persist.

Answer (score 0):

**Doyousketch2** did provide the relevant clues to solving this. What I did to run `make` successfully was:

```
make CMAKE_ARGS="-DGENERATE_DOC:BOOLEAN=OFF"
```